# Recovering binary data from MongoDB using Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a field in a MongoDB collection which stores an image as a binary as follows:

```
with open(image['url'], "rb") as f:
    encoded = Binary(f.read())
    image['data'] = encoded
    # ... This gets inserted into the DB
```

Now, I export the collection as:

```
img_records = dumps(db.imagecollection.find({}, {'_id': False}))
```

This has the `data` field which seems to be base64 encoded, so I get something like:

```
'data': {'$binary': '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/4QH4RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACgE
```

So what I am trying to do is load it back into the field. I am not sure how to load this back into the `Binary` structure so that I can restore the record from this string representation. So, this `Binary` class inputs a `bytes` stream and I have this base64 encoded string.

Comment: In case someone is interested, this did the trick:
`decoded = base64.decodebytes(imagecollection['data']['$binary'].encode())`

Comment: Please post it as a answer so it will be easier to find for others looking for same.